# Pivoting longer for sequential data with various datatypes in R using pivot_longer

Tags: r, dataframe

To create graphs from my data that is currently in the wide format, I am trying to pivot this data to a longer format. Currently the data is like this:

| type | parameter_d1 | parameter_d2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 8 |
| 1 | 6 | 5 |

In reality there is many different parameters, but they all have the suffix _d1 and _d2.

Finally I would like to have a dataframe like the following:

| type | day | parameter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 4 |
| 0 | 2 | 8 |
| 1 | 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |

I think this shouldn't be too hard to achieve but I can't find an example doing this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use matching groups and regular expression in the `names_pattern` argument in  `pivot_longer` to do so. See the example below [that I adjusted from a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73717099/how-to-generate-multiple-geom-errorbar-for-each-geom-line-in-ggplot/73718441#73718441), where the parameters are `y` or `se`, and days are numbers:

```r
library("tidyverse")

# Some data
raw_data <- data.frame(x = seq(10),
                       y_d1 = sample(x=20,size=10), # c(1.1, 2.4, 3.5, 4.1, 5.9, 6.7, 7.1, 8.3, 9.4, 10.0)
                       y_d2 = sample(x=20,size=10),
                       y_d3 = sample(x=20,size=10),
                       y_d4 = sample(x=20,size=10),
                       se_d1 = runif(n=10,min=0,max=1),
                       se_d2 = runif(n=10,min=0,max=1),
                       se_d3 = runif(n=10,min=0,max=1),
                       se_d4 = runif(n=10,min=0,max=1))

# Convert to a long format
raw_data %>%
  pivot_longer(!x,
               names_pattern = "([[:alpha:]]+)_d([0-9])",
               names_to = c("parameter", "day"))
#> # A tibble: 80 x 4
#>        x parameter day    value
#>    <int> <chr>     <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1     1 y         1     12    
#>  2     1 y         2      1    
#>  3     1 y         3     12    
#>  4     1 y         4      9    
#>  5     1 se        1      0.840
#>  6     1 se        2      0.650
#>  7     1 se        3      0.523
#>  8     1 se        4      0.211
#>  9     2 y         1     15    
#> 10     2 y         2      6    
#> # ... with 70 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with `pivot_longer`:

```r
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-type, names_sep = "_", names_to = c(".value", "day"), 
               names_transform = list(day = readr::parse_number))

   type   day parameter
1     0     1         4
2     0     2         8
3     1     1         6
4     1     2         5
```